Amiga Forever fullscreen mode is display on second monitor instead of first monitor
I'm using Amiga Forever on Windows 11 with two monitors.
Now I have a recent new problem with the fullscreen mode in Amiga Forever (It used to work correctly).
If the Amiga Forever program is on monitor 1 and I press the Fullscreen button

the fullscreen appears correctly, but on monitor 2.

I want it to be displayed on monitor 1 instead of monitor 2.

This isn't about retrocomputing. This is about how to use modern software, latest release being about six months old. Surely the people that sold it to you have a support forum?

I found the solution: https://www.amigaforever.com/kb/15-121 — Use Tools -> Options. Then Emulation -> Fullscreen -> Display

Shift-Windows Key-Left Arrow
or
Shift-Windows Key-Right Arrow
will move the window that currently has focus between monitors.

Just tried you solution, but that didn't work. Nothing happens when I tries to move the Amiga Forever window/program with the help of the Shift + Windows + Arrow Keys. It works fine on other windows though...

This likely won't work correctly because Amiga emulators usually map the Windows keys as the left and right Amiga keys. You'd have to either remap the Amiga keys inside the emulator to something else or remap the window move shortcuts to different keys in Windows.
